# AJAX search function resets wp_query vars

Tags: wp-query, ajax, jquery

I have a custom post type called `event`. On the archive page I implemented a simple search which returns a selection of posts. Before submitting the search form I'm seeing the proper query vars for the archive page. Once I submit the search form those query vars are removed and return an empty string. I have a few conditionals depending on things like current_post and post_count. Can the ajax call re-populate those variables? How do I get those variables back?

```
<form id="siteSearchForm" action="<?= admin_url('admin-ajax.php') ?>" method="POST">
    <input type="search" name="s" id="search" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" placeholder="Search Events" />
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="eventsFilter" />
    <input type="submit" id="search-submit" alt="Search" value="Search" class="btn btn-white" />
</form>
```

The JS:

```
const searchFunctionality = ($) => {
    $('#siteSearchForm').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const search = $('#siteSearchForm');

        $.ajax({
            data: {
                action: 'eventsFilter', // ajax function name
                keyword: $('#search').val(), // search word
            },
            type: search.attr('method'),
            url: search.attr('action'),
            success: function (data) {
                $('.events-wrapper').html(data);
            },
        });

        return false;
    });
};
```

and finally the AJAX php function:

```
<?php
add_action('wp_ajax_eventsFilter', 'events_filter');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_eventsFilter', 'events_filter');

function events_filter()
{
    $args = array( // match paramters found in pre_get_posts (/theme.php)
        'meta_key'       => 'event_start_date',
        'order'          => 'ASC',
        'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'post_type'      => 'event',
        's'              => $_POST["keyword"],
        'tag__not_in'    => array(16),
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($query->have_posts()) :
        while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
            get_template_part('template-parts/content/content', 'archive');
        endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();
    else :
        echo 'No posts found';
    endif;

    die();
}
```

Comment: What is the code that reads these query vars and where is it used?

Comment: If you mean the conditionals, I have some if ($wp_query -> current_post === 1 ) else statements on the event archive page. When you land on the page it works, but when you submit the form the current_post variable isn't set any longer. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Your AJAX code replaces `.events-wrapper` with the AJAX response. It’s not replacing any variables. AJAX can’t do that. If you have logic in your archive template inside the wrapper then that logic would also need to be in the AJAX handler if you’re replacing it.

Comment: The problem is not the ajax response. The problem is that the variables from WP are getting replaced. If before the AJAX executes the query vars contained variables like `post_count`, after the AJAX response that's gone. I don't think ajax is able to inject things into the PHP variables of WordPress (happy to be wrong here)

Comment: It's literally impossible for variables from WP to be "replaced" by an AJAX response. That's not how any of these technologies work. So I'm trying to understand what's actually happening. What is actually happening that makes you think that the `post_count` query var is being replaced?

Comment: If you mean that inside `template-parts/content/content/archive.php` in your AJAX response that some variable is not what you expect it to be, then that's a misunderstanding of how AJAX works. If you load a page, WordPress will run and set all sorts of variables which could be used in the template. If you then send an AJAX request in the browser from that page, then that is a whole new request. _Nothing_ will persist from the original page load unless it was stored in the database. Your `events_filter()` AJAX handler knows nothing about the original page load.

Comment: I understand. Let me rephrase: I navigate to archive-events and var_dump ```$wp_query -> current_post``` & ```$wp_query -> post_count```. Both have proper values (current post = 1 - incrementing with each post. post_count = 10). Then I use the Ajax filter to search for a specific post. current_post goes to -1 and post_count goes to 0 (although I'm showing posts returned from Ajax). The events_filter function in php is running a new query to return filtered results so my hope was that it reflected the post_count/current_post in the query vars.How do I keep current_post and post_count accurate?